# Monthly and Yearly Report in one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table whose output is this [image]

i have written my query like this

```
SELECT 
 c.DivisionNameEn,
a.LF_CompanyDivisionID, 
0 as code, 
 SUM(a.totInvoiceAmnt) AS Sales,
 'Sales'   Salesperson,
 sum(a.totInvoiceAmnt) as Sum ,
 sum(a.totInvoiceAmnt) /sum(a.totInvoiceAmnt) *100 as MonthPercent ,
    YEAR(a.TransactionDate) [Year],
    MONTH(a.TransactionDate) [Month],

   CASE 
         WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  1 THEN  SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  2 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  3 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  4 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  5 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  6 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  7 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
              WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  8 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
               WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  9 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)              
         WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  10 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  11 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             WHEN datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) =  12 THEN SUM(CASE datepart(month,a.TransactionDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         ELSE 0
      END as MonthTotal
from POS_salesHeader a 
INNER JOIN  dbo.STR_CompanyDivision AS c ON c.id = a.LF_CompanyDivisionID
--WHERE YEAR(a.TransactionDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(a.TransactionDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) /*To filter by month*/
GROUP BY  YEAR(a.TransactionDate), MONTH(a.TransactionDate) , c.DivisionNameEn ,LF_CompanyDivisionID
```

it is giving me out put like this 
[image]

I want a row which give me month Total totInvoiceAmnt and till now Year Total totInvoiceAmnt for example if today its 15th April  it gives me total totInvoiceAmnt of only April with the column name MonthsTotal and in another column it give me till now yearly totInvoiceAmnt total from month of jan + Feb + March +April

Comment: So select inside th case with a where clause `WHERE MONTH(Col) = 4`

Comment: Also why you are using `SUM()` don't you mean `COUNT()`?

Comment: the current month total should just be `sum(case when month(a.TransactionDate) = month(getdate()) then totInvoiceAmnt end)` or `count(case when month(a.TransactionDate) = month(getdate()) then 1 end)`

Comment: I don't understand what the CASE statement is trying to achieve. What is actually being totalled into MonthTotal?

Comment: Ok Jamie your suggestion is working sum(case when month(a.TransactionDate) = month(getdate()) then totInvoiceAmnt end) how can i take total of the as of todays date i mean from 1st Jan to 15th April consider today is 15th April 2017

Comment: you can say `sum(case when TransactionDate between datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) and getdate() then totInvoiceAmnt end)`

Comment: to clean up the case statement you can use `case datepart(month,a.TransactionDate)  when 1 then .... `

Comment: No Jamie in case of year its not working